# How to convert a custom date format to an alternate format with the gnu 'date' command?

Tags: shell, date

I have a string with a custom date format written in Japanese: `2013年1月8日 20時19分`. With osx's `date` command, I can convert this to some other format with the following command:

```
timestamp="2013年1月8日 20時19分"
date -j -f "%Y年%m月%d日 %H時%M分" "$timestamp" +"%F %R"
```

While searching I found [this question helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279329/how-can-i-change-the-format-of-a-date-from-the-command-line), but it ultimately did not help when it came to gnu `date`. The command `gdate -d "2013年1月8日 20時19分" +"%F %R"` fails saying that it does not understand the date format. The `-d` flag allows some simple formats, but how I can apply a more radical custom format and convert the date? Am I stuck with parsing the string myself with string manipulation in shell?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a simple problem of having `LANG=C` instead of a `UTF-8` locale? Under date (`--version == coreutils 8.13`) your `gdate` example works.

Comment: @Petesh , running `LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 gdate -d "2013年1月8日 20時19分" +"%F %R"` fails on my computer. Originally my LANG was `en_US.UTF-8`, but I had already attempted changing it to Japanese specific. `--version == "date (GNU coreutils) 8.20"`.

Comment: I just signed into a Linux box (originally was on osx) and tested the above example. It worked on your date version 8.13. Could this be a bug introduced in newer versions of date?

Comment: Actually, the date produced by coreutils 8.13 is wrong. It produced `2013-01-09 20:13` which is wrong. It should be `2013-01-08 20:19`. I didn't notice it because the date was specifically easy to misdiagnose. @Petesh are you also seeing this?

Comment: It seems to not be parsing the date properly at all. Unfortunately GNU date does not support specifying the strprime for parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out with the aid of the [coreutils mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2013-01/msg00028.html). However, the example they give there uses perl. They specifically rely on the POSIX::strptime module, which does not come with a standard installation of perl. Therefore, I solved this with python, which has the `time` module. This module should be available in most installations of python2 and python3.

Here's how to use it programmatically:

#### Python solution:

```
$ timestamp='2013年1月8日 20時19分'
$ time_format='%Y年%m月%d日 %H時%M分'
$ gdate -u -R -d "$(python -c 'import sys; from time import strptime; t=strptime(sys.argv[-1],"'$time_format'"); print("%d-%d-%d %d:%d"%(t.tm_year,t.tm_mon,t.tm_mday,t.tm_hour,t.tm_min))' $timestamp)"
Tue, 08 Jan 2013 20:19:00 +0000
```

This works with both python2 and python3. You can substitute any timestamp and format as you like.

#### Perl solution

To document the answer given to me on coreutils, the perl solution is this (requires `POSIX::strptime`)

```
$ gdate -u -R -d "$(perl -MPOSIX::strptime -le 'my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday) = POSIX::strptime("$ARGV[0]","%Y年%m月%d日 %H時%M分");$year+=1900;$mon+=1;printf("%04d-%02d-%02d %0d:%02d\n",$year,$mon,$mday,$hour,$min);' "2013年1月8日 20時19分")"
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Please add also the Perl way (most dev systems have Perl but not Python, it will make the answer more usefull)

Answer (score 1):

You probably will have to tinker with some environment variables (ex: `TZ`, `LC_ALL`, etc).

See [this page showing you most of the common environnement variables, and their meanings](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html)

To try some: you can force the value to change *just for the duration of the following command* by putting them on the same line, before the command itself:

`TZ=....  LC_LANG=..... date -d .......`

will invoke `date -d ....` with the 2 environment variables `TZ` and `LC_LANG` set to a temporary value.

Some interresting pointers (I can't right now tell if there **is** a program that will take as input any locale's date and translate that to the relevant Epoch or Unix Timestamp... BUt there seems to be hope following that (looking quite standard) trail of online docs:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_02

which talks, amongst many other, about:

```
LC_TIME
    This variable shall determine the locale category for date and time formatting information. It affects the behavior of the time functions in strftime(). Additional semantics of this variable, if any, are implementation-defined.
```

Which points to: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdate.html

which says in the middle:

```
The match between the template and input specification performed by getdate() shall be case-insensitive.

The month and weekday names can consist of any combination of upper and lowercase letters. The process can request that the input date or time specification be in a specific language by setting the LC_TIME category (see setlocale ).
```

and points to: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html

... I wish you an happy reading ! Let us know what you find!

Comment: I got close, but it seems that the `-d` can't use region specific formats while the output can be region specific. I had `TZ=JST-9 LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8 gdate` and it produces `水  1  9 07:57:14 JST 2013`, which is formatted in Japanese. If I run `gdate -d Wed '+%a'`, I get the day of the week `水`, but run in reverse, `gdate -d 水 '+%a'` produces an error. Any thoughts?

Comment: this is quite hard to do in a general way, and i can't find a tool for it. You'll need to either : ask the provider of the logs to switch to (UTC-based) timestamps (or Epoch), or ask a thourough speaker of the langage to provide some `sed` filters translating it to a all-numeric format (ex:  2012/12/16__16:43:40s-456ms).

Comment: fascinating stuff, i'll update my answer with some (tiny hope) pointers of good docs to start reading about it (But I let you do it ^^ I don't have time now to delve in it, but will surely go back to it at some point)

Comment: using `perl` to search/replace unicode-specific dates strings (months, day-of-week, etc) from the japanese/whatever original to a "standard" machine-readable (`date` readable) format, and then use the `date` utility to process that input, seems your easiest bet right now. Don't try to do your own date-converting program, it's incredibly surprising and difficult (many, many weird stuff happened overtime, in different countries, making the time or date jump back/forward in weird ways at weird times... don't try to cover it all!)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I read through some of it, and while it seems like I may be able to create a custom locale date format that is recognizable, I might end up being required to add it to an `/etc` file (perhaps I didn't read carefully enough), which is no good. That being said, if I assume the dateformat goes unchanged, I can simply use `echo $timestamp | sed -e 's/年/-/' -e 's/月/-/' -e 's/日//' -e 's/時/:/' -e 's/分//'`, which gives a format that *is* useable by `date`.

Comment: Also, I posted a question to the coreutils mailing list because there are bound to be some experts there who have done this and can tell me if it is worth exploring beyond simple character conversion like with `sed`. I'll be back to let you know what I find out.

Comment: I hope they will answer, it bothers me too ^^ And you don't need to change /etc, just the LC_* variables inside the script (at least at first).

Comment: So, there is actually a way to get this done by sending out to another process (perl is the example used, others are viable, too), but it requires the POSIX::strptime module which is not in a default perl installation. So, there is no pure `date` method to solve this easily. The answer to my question on the coreutils list gives the details < http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2013-01/msg00028.html >

Comment: It's in python's `time` module as a function, though. I'll write up an example

Comment: my answer below gives the shell commands to accomplish this. It should work on most systems.