# shell script to replace date format in an xml document

Tags: shell, date, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the format of a date from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279329/how-can-i-change-the-format-of-a-date-from-the-command-line)

I'm running a nightly cron job that downloads and XML file. The XML file has dates formatted like this:

```
<date>2011-09-30</date>
```

I'd like to set up a second cron job that changes each date to be formatted like this:

```
<date>September 30</date>
```

and then saves the file.

Is there a good way to do this with a shell script?

Comment: I'm sure this could be done with a call to sed... But me personally I'd use an XML tool like http://nokogiri.org/ to do something like this. Just personal preference as hacking XML with string replacement leads to issues down the road if the format changes, etc.

Comment: @Kansha, see my post, that's why I show a pure Xpath solution in shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
date '+%Y-%m-%dT%T.%N'
```

Comment: could you explain how i can use it?

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [Xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) and shell tools:

The XML sample:

```
$ cat sample.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doc>
<date>2011-09-30</date>
</doc>
```

Getting the date with `xmllint` and [Xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath):

```
$ dat=$(xmllint --xpath '/doc/date/text()' sample.xml )
$ echo $dat
2011-09-30
```

Now, translating the format of the date :

```
$ new_dat=$(date -d "$dat" "+%B %d")
```

(if you want the current date instead, just use `new_dat=$(date "+%B %d")`)

Editing the xml with `xmlstarlet` :

```
$ xmlstarlet edit -L -u "/doc/date" -v "$new_dat" sample.xml
```

Finally

```
$ cat sample.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doc>
  <date>septembre 30</date>
</doc>
```

Comment: so I'm running the following shell file:

`#!/bin/sh

dat=$(xmllint --xpath '/doc/date/text()' path/to/file.xml
new_dat=$(date -d "$dat" "+%B %d") )
xmlstarlet edit -L -u "/doc/date" -v "$new_dat" path/to/file.xml`

and the server gives me the following error:
`line 5: xmlstarlet: command not found`

(it's for a friend, who uses godaddy unfortunately)

Comment: The error is very clear : you need to install xmlstarlet.

Answer (score 0):

Bash syntax to filter (standard input to std output) a file with one date format into the other...

```
while read line; do
  case "$line" in
    '<date>'*)
      echo '<date>'
      date -j -f %F `echo "$line" | sed -e 's/<date>//' -e 's-</date>--'` '+%B %d'
      echo '</date>'
      ;;
    *)
      echo "$line"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: i got this working locally, but godaddy's shell throws an error:

`date: invalid option -- 'j'`